# Customise Sankey Highcharts marker and link width

Tags: highcharts, sankey-diagram

I am implementing a Sankey charts using Highcharts where I need to display each nodes in specific symbol. I want to implement marker symbol feature for my Sankey graph.

I tried using marker.symbol which is not working.

```js
marker: {
  symbol: 'triangle'
}
```

Is there a way to implement custom symbols for Sankey graph? Also is there a way where I can control the width of links between each nodes? All my nodes have same weight, hence I want a way to fix my width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts does not provide options that will allow to modify the marker symbol and the link width for `sankey` chart type, so it is not possible by default.

**Workaround**

- To modify the links width, set `scale` and `translate` attributes.
- To change the markers, use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` and replace default rects by triangles.

  ```
  chart: {
      height: 200,
      events: {
          load: function() {
              var points = this.series[0].points,
                  fromNodeBBox,
                  toNodeBBox,
                  linkBBox;

              points.forEach(function(p) {
                  fromNodeBBox = p.fromNode.graphic.getBBox();
                  toNodeBBox = p.toNode.graphic.getBBox();

                  this.renderer.symbol(
                      'triangle',
                      fromNodeBBox.x + this.plotLeft + 10,
                      fromNodeBBox.y + this.plotTop,
                      fromNodeBBox.width,
                      fromNodeBBox.height
                  ).attr({
                      fill: p.fromNode.color
                  }).add();

                  this.renderer.symbol(
                      'triangle',
                      toNodeBBox.x + this.plotLeft - 10,
                      toNodeBBox.y + this.plotTop,
                      toNodeBBox.width,
                      toNodeBBox.height
                  ).attr({
                      fill: p.toNode.color,
                      zIndex: 3
                  }).add();


                  linkBBox = p.graphic.getBBox();
                  p.graphic.attr({
                      transform: 'scale(1 0.5) translate(0 ' + (linkBBox.y + fromNodeBBox.height / 2) + ')'
                  });

                  p.fromNode.graphic.destroy();
                  p.toNode.graphic.destroy();
              }, this);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f4u03qvd/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#symbol

Comment: Thanks ppotaczek !!.

This works great only when I have one level of from node and two nodes. but my app has multiple levels of from node and to nodes, something like

['A', 'B', 1],
['A', 'C', 1],
['C', 'D', 1],
['C', 'E', 1]

In this case, I get an error as below. Any idea on how to resolve this?
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined
    at a.SVGElement.getBBox (highcharts.src.js:4787)
    at a.Chart.<anonymous> ((index):76)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at a.Chart.load ((index):75)
    at highcharts.src.js:2624
    at Array.forEach

Comment: Hi Guru, Yes, you have to adapt this solution to other cases, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gpdhrt85/

Comment: Thanks ppotaczek for your help. I will adapt thia as per my requirement. This helped a lot!!

Comment: I want to make all links with the same small width - 1-1.5 mm. I want to add arrows to the end of these lines. Is that possible?

Comment: Hi @Mark, Please create a new question with `highcharts` tag.